# Creación de un tipo decimal personalizado para Protobuf

Tags: c#, dotnetcore, protobuf

Tengo la siguiente duda:

Estoy siguiendo la implementación de un tipo de dato personalizado para soportar el tipo de datos decimal en la comunicación gRPC siguiente la documentación de microsoft.

https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/architecture/grpc-for-wcf-developers/protobuf-data-types#creating-a-custom-decimal-type-for-protobuf

Esto con el fin datos en formato moneda ya que float y double no son precisos para este tipo de información.

El inconveniente que tengo actualmente es porque estoy haciendo uso de los option para generar la comunicación a través de rest:

```
syntax = "proto3";

import "customTypes.proto";

message FooRpc {
   customTypes.DecimalValue price = 1;
}

message FindFooResponse {
  repeated FooRpc foo = 1;
}

rpc FindFoo(google.protobuf.Empty) returns (FindFooResponse) {
    option (google.api.http) = {
      get: "/api/v1/foo"
    };
  }
```

Por lo cual al momento de realizar una solicitud la documentación y autogeneración de código al momento de usar las clases generadas luego de compilar los proto.

Me sale de estar forma:

```
{
  "units": 0,
  "nanos": 0
}
```

A pesar de que envió los datos de esta forma:

```
{
  "units": 200,
  "nanos": 990000000
}
```

La respuesta que obtengo es esta:

```
{
  "units": "0",
  "nanos": 0
}
```

Los datos se almacenan correctamente en la base de datos ya que se realiza la conversión.
Pero al momento de enviar los datos al cliente se reflejan como lo mencione anteriormente:

Código dotnet c#:

```
public override async Task<FindFooResponse> FindFoo(Empty request, ServerCallContext context)
    {
        var response = await _mediator.Send(new FooQueryRequest());

        // map handler response to grpc model
        return response.Adapt<FindFooResponse>();
    }
```

Me gustaría saber si este comportamiento es normal, o lo que estoy tratando de hacer no es posible, o si por el contrario hay una forma de hacer la implementación y se usada tanto en gRPC como en API.